# Ctrl + ^ shortcut not working correctly

Tags: keyboard

As expect I'm getting a blank superscript input graphic, however, I'm also being directed to the beginning of the document

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior on my system (Win10-64, MMA 12). Is it possible that you / another program have defined a keyboard shortcut linked to that combination?